# Unable to load Renderable when trying to implement ar core

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

Why am i getting this error when trying to create an ar app?

```
Unable to load Renderable registryId='android.resource://com.nevco.ar/raw/cat'
    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.AssertionError: No RCB file at uri: android.resource://com.nevco.ar/raw/cat
```

I am folliwng this tutorial to create a simple ar app, but everytime i launch my app i keep getting this error. I am not sure what to do to fix this. Some help would be grealty appreciated. I attached the link to the tutorial.  https://www.androidauthority.com/google-arcore-972579/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

//Create a member variable for ModelRenderable//

    private ModelRenderable dinoRenderable;

//Create a member variable for ArFragment//

    private ArFragment arCoreFragment;

    @RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!checkDevice((this))) {
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arCoreFragment = (ArFragment)

//Find the fragment, using fragment manager//

                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N) {

//Build the ModelRenderable//

            ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this, R.raw.cat)
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(renderable -> dinoRenderable = renderable)
                    .exceptionally(

//If an error occurs...//

                            throwable -> {

//...then print the following message to Logcat//

                                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load renderable");
                                return null;
                            });
        }

//Listen for onTap events//

        arCoreFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
                (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
                    if (dinoRenderable == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

//Build a node of type AnchorNode//

                    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

//Connect the AnchorNode to the Scene//

                    anchorNode.setParent(arCoreFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

//Build a node of type TransformableNode//

                    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arCoreFragment.getTransformationSystem());

//Connect the TransformableNode to the AnchorNode//

                    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);

//Attach the Renderable//

                    transformableNode.setRenderable(dinoRenderable);

//Set the node//

                    transformableNode.select();
                });
    }

    public static boolean checkDevice(final Activity activity) {

//If the device is running Android Marshmallow or earlier...//

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.N) {

//...then print the following message to Logcat//

            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or higher");
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        String openGlVersionString =
                ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()

//Check the version of OpenGL ES//

                        .getGlEsVersion();

//If the device is running anything less than OpenGL ES 3.0...//

        if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {

//...then print the following message to Logcat//

            Log.e(TAG, "Requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher");
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey! did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No i have not :( have you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create a node and add renderable of the model in it then attach it to the arFragment. You just used the renderable directly without creating a node. There you are getting the error. Check the below code **addNodeToScene()** method.

Try the following code,

```
package com.example.arcorefirst;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

    ArFragment arFragment;
    ModelRenderable lampPostRenderable;
    private Uri selectedObject;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);
        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
                (HitResult hitresult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionevent) -> {
                    if (plane.getType() != Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING)
                        return;

                    Anchor anchor = hitresult.createAnchor();
                    placeObject(arFragment, anchor, R.raw.cube);
                }
        );
    }

    private void placeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, int uri) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                }
            );
    }

    private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        node.select();
    }

}
```

For more checkout my repo:

[codemaker2015/ar-object-augmentation-android-studio](https://github.com/codemaker2015/ar-object-augmentation-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your model is *.sfb* file or *.obj* file.

*.sfb* is working for me, but I get the same error with *.obj*.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that filament identified it as sfb.

```
Include .setIsFilamentGltf(true)

ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(
                        this,
                        Uri.parse(path))
                .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                .build()
```